# start a python script when there is insertion in table and stop the script when there is a column update in table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psql

I am using PostgreSQL.

How can I automatically start a python script when there is a insertion happening in a table, and similarly how to stop the same script if a column of a table in updated.

Example: if I have a table with a column `isProgramstopped` whose boolean value is `false`. When `isProgramstopped` is updated to `true`, the python script should be stopped.

Is there any way?